# Correct use of indefinite articles with plural objects and singular subjects

Tags: prépositions, articles, pluriel, déterminants

What is the correct form of the given two:

> [La] transplantation de vaisseaux lymphatiques périphériques

or

> [La] transplantation des vaisseaux lymphatiques périphériques

Comment: Please, give more context. Both can be correct depending on what you want to say precisely.

Comment: Actually, that is all context I have. Its a medical procedure.

Comment: Is it the beginning of a sentence, or a title ?

Comment: In French (not English), the DE is the notion, whereas the DES means the actual thing is done to objects. La Vie d'Abeille [the notion of the life of a bee, bee life]. La vie des abeilles, the (actual life) of bees.

Comment: Both are correct, they mean different things (see the duplicate question). @Lambie This isn't about “la vie d'abeille” but “la vie d'abeilles” vs “la vie des abeilles”.

Comment: Did I say either was wrong? Yes, I miswrote: I meant to write: La vie d'abeilles with an s. I was explaining the difference in French, which doesn't work in English.